# How to use a local domain socket in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, sockets, networking

Objective-C makes it very easy to use network sockets with streams doing something like this:

```
// Setup comms with the server, assumed to be running on the local host
NSHost* host = [NSHost hostWithAddress:@"127.0.0.1"];

NSInputStream *iStream;
NSOutputStream *oStream;

[NSStream getStreamsToHost:host port:_PORT inputStream: &iStream outputStream: &oStream];
```

However, is it possible to create and or connect to a [local domain socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_domain_socket) this way, or does Objective-C provide other classes for this?

If I can still use NSStream and getStreamsToHost, how would I specify the file and what would I put for the port number?

My research on this, so far, shows many examples working with TCP/IP or UDP, but not local domain sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t use `-getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:` for a UNIX domain socket, no.  You can, however, create your own `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` instances; the easiest way is to take advantage of toll-free bridging between `CF(Read|Write)Stream` and `NS(Input|Output)Stream`; for instance:

```
struct sockaddr_un sun;

sun.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy (sun.sun_path, "/path/to/my/socket");
sun.sun_len = SUN_LEN(&sun);

// Server side (naive)
int server_sock = socket (SOCK_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
int ret = bind (server_sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sun, sun.sun_len);

listen (server_sock, 1);               // In practice you'd specify more than 1

s = accept (server_sock, NULL, NULL);  // In practice you want to keep calling this

// Client side
int s = socket (SOCK_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

int ret = connect (s, (struct sockaddr *)&sun, sun.sun_len);

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocket (kCFAllocatorDefault, s, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

Then to get an `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` you can just do

```
NSInputStream *inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
NSOutputStream *outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputSteram *)outputStream;
```

Obviously in practice you may want to wrap all of the above in a function or method in your own code.  Also, take care with `sockaddr_un`; the `sun_path` member was probably supposed to have 1024 characters, but in the headers it seems to only have 104 (this is a long-standing problem and apparently goes way back to BSD4.4; some systems have other character counts here too).  This is nowhere near `PATH_MAX`, so in practice you may wish to write something more like

```
struct sockaddr_un *new_unix_addr (const char *path) {
  size_t len = strlen (path);
  size_t bytes = sizeof (struct sockaddr_un) + len + 1
                 - sizeof (((struct sockaddr_un *)0)->sun_path);
  struct sockaddr_un *pun = (struct sockaddr_un *)malloc (bytes);

  pun->sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  pun->sun_len = bytes;
  memcpy (pun->sun_path, path, len + 1);
  return pun;
}
```

remembering later to `free()` it.

Comment: I am not sure if 1024 *accidentally* became 104 in the definition of `sun_path`, it is 104 or 108 on other platforms as well (Linux, Solaris). Compare http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/sys/un.h.html.

Comment: @MartinR Looks like it’s a very old accident, then :-)

Comment: Unix domain sockets probably existed *before* such long path names were allowed in Unix systems. - I am also not sure if you can simply allocate a larger sockaddr_un (did you try it?). That would require that the *kernel* can cope with a larger path. The POSIX specification states that *"Applications should not assume a particular length for sun_path or assume that it can hold {_POSIX_PATH_MAX} characters (255)."*

Comment: @MartinR Haven't tried it, but I’d expect if the kernel doesn’t support it that it would fail with an error code, which is better than a buffer overrun.  And if it *does* support it, then it will work.  Seems a reasonable choice.

Comment: Thanks, this all looks good, though I'm having a problem connecting to the created socket. I've previously written a program in Qt, which can create sockets that I can connect to. That socket file has the permissions of sxrwxrw-rw-, but the code you've posted creates the file with srwxr-xr-x permissions. Both sockets are owned by the same user and group. I can't telnet to the socket created by the above code as it states that permission is denied. Any ideas why the permissions are different? Even if I chmod the file to 777, it still fails to allow a connection.

Comment: Should I need to call listen too? I've tried adding listen(SOCK_STREAM, 1), but it returns with the error ENOTSOCK "Socket operation on non-socket"

Comment: If you’re creating a server socket, you need to call `listen(s, <some number>)`, yes.  You’ll also need to call `accept(s)` to accept an incoming connection, and that will return a new socket that you’ll need to use to create your input/output streams.

Comment: Ah, I got it, thanks. Could you please update your answer to include this too? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Merlin069 it’s a little out of the scope of the question, and you should probably consult a book on BSD sockets programming at this point, however I have improved the answer a bit to make it clear you need to use `listen()` and `accept()` in the server case.